# Increment a number by 1 if it is greater than a value

Tags: jquery

I have a list into which I have inserted a new row. I want all the sequence numbers after it to increase by one.

```
<div class="modal" id="insertroom" style="display: none;">
    <button class="dismiss right button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
    <h3>Insert a room in the route</h3>
    <p><span class="fixed-width">Room name:</span>
       <input name="room_id" id="room_id"/>
          </p>
      <p><span class="fixed-width">Sequence number in the route:</span> <input type="number" id="newsequencenumber" name="sequence" value=""></p>
    <p><span class="fixed-width">Route name:</span>
       <input name="route_number" id="route_number"/>
          </p>
     <p><input type="button" class="button" id="insertdetails" name="insertdetails" value="Insert details"></p>
</div>

   <ul class="ui-listview">
      <li><span class="half-fixed-width">AB101B</span> 
     Sequence: 
         <input type="number" class="sequence" name="sequence" value="1"> 
         <a class="button inserthere" title="insert room here" href="#" rel="1">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
         </a> 
      </li>
```

I wrote the below code, but it seems to be ignoring the `if(new_sequence_number > thisval)` part, because it increments all the numbers by 1, rather than only ones with a value greater than the sequence number of the inserted row.

```
 $('#insertdetails').on('click', function() {
  /*get values input into modal */
  var new_sequence_number = $('#insertroom #newsequencenumber').val();
  var new_room_id = $('#insertroom #room_id').val();
  var new_route_id = $('#insertroom #route_number').val();
  /*put those values into the new row */
  $('#new_room_id' + new_sequence_number).val(new_room_id);
  $('#new_route_id' + new_sequence_number).val(new_route_id);
  $('#insertroom').hide();
  $('.overlay').hide();

  $('.sequence').filter(function(new_sequence_number) {
    var thisval = parseInt($(this).val());
    var plusone = thisval + 1;
    if(thisval > new_sequence_number) {
      $(this).val(plusone);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I checked all the questions with a similar title but none of them solved my problem

Comment: The parameter you've named `new_sequence_number` will be the index of the element in the set - is that what you're expecting it to be? It may help to see a working snippet if you could set one up - or at least the associated HTML

Comment: If your explanation is correct, the you have the wrong IF clause. It should be `thisval > new_sequence_number`. You said if the value is greater than the sequence number.

Comment: thanks @yomisimie you are right, but it still doesn't work even with that the right way round

Comment: can you provide your html code

Comment: for Rory and Trimantra, I have now added the html and the rest of the jQuery.

Comment: The `new_sequence_number` in the function parameter is a *new* variable and will not refer to the 'new_sequence_number' declared above it. The parameter can be omitted to use the outer variable. The `each` you had before the edit is better than the `filter`, if the loop is maintained in this state. Untested, but the following should work: `$('.sequence').each(function() {`

Comment: thanks so much @Me.Name - that worked. I actually needed `if(thisval >= new_sequence_number)` to ensure that the one with the same value is also incremented. If you post that as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new_sequence_number` in the function parameter is a new variable and will not refer to the 'new_sequence_number' declared above it. The parameter can be omitted to use the outer variable.

```
  $('.sequence').each(function() {
    // ..
    if(thisval >= new_sequence_number) {
    //....
```

---

Purely because the answer seems so short in itself, below is an alternative :D

`val()` can take a function as an argument in which the value can be manipulated. The downside of this method is that all inputs are set, even if they remain the same. The upside is that all the logic is in a short and single function call.

```
  $('.sequence').val(function(ind,v) {      
    return (v = +v) < new_sequence_number ? v : ++v;
  });
```

Comment: thanks. I used the first one and it is working perfectly